# Refresh token with expo auth sessions (Google)

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication

I use for my Android app expo-auth-sessions to authorize the user via Google:

```
  const [request, response, promptAssync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
    iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
    expoClientId: EXPO_CLIENT_ID,
    scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    ],
  })
```

The request works just fine and it returns an access token, but it does not contain a refresh token.

Is there any possibility to configure the request that it also returns a refresh token or something similar to not force the user to sign in again after the access token expires?

Current response:

```
{
    authentication: {
      accessToken: TOKEN,
      expiresIn: "3599",
      idToken: undefined,
      issuedAt: 1644693943,
      refreshToken: undefined,
      scope:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      tokenType: "Bearer",
    },
    params: {
      access_token: TOKEN,
      expires_in: "3599",
      scope:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      token_type: "Bearer",
    },
    type: "success"
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add `access_type: "offline"` ([Google APIs auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest)) in your auth URL because expo doesn't do that by default. For this, you can make use of the `extraParams` attribute in `useAuthSession`. However, `access_type: "offline"` is not supported for `responseType: "token"` (the default value) since the concept of `refresh_token` doesn't exist for `implicit_grant_flow`. You'll have to change that to `responseType: "code"` and later exchange the obtained code for access and refresh token on the server side. Overall you'll have to make the following changes -

```
const [request, response, promptAssync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  androidClientId: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
  iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
  expoClientId: EXPO_CLIENT_ID,
  scopes: [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  ],
  responseType: "code",
  shouldAutoExchangeCode: false,
  extraParams: {
    access_type: "offline"
  },
})
```

However, if you've already authorized the app once before, you might have to add `prompt: 'consent'` too. You can take a look at this answer for more clarity - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/213#issuecomment-205886341

Comment: tried this and with prompt: 'consent'. it seems that adding access_type offline just makes response.authentication = null. And I don't see how to access refresh token anywhere on response.